# Custom Categories and Sub Categories for UserControl's Custom Properties

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have create a `UserControl` and some **custom properties** for it but I want to **group** them into a **custom category** with "**sub categories**". Something like that.

```
|+| Custom Category Name
    |+| Custom Sub Category
        |+| My Property
              My Value1 Header: Value1
              My Value2 Header: Value2
OR

|+| Custom Category Name
    |+| Custom Sub Category
           My Property: Value
```

I know how to make custom properties and add them into custom categories, but how can I make sub categories and add my custom properties in?

Comment: It sounds a lot like you want to store external data in your control as individual properties. Ideally the properties of a control, contain just that. Control properties. What sort of control is it and what sort of data do you want to store?

Comment: It's a `UserControl` with some **custom properties** which I have create, like `CustomBackColor`, `CustomFont` and much more and I want to make separate groups for those properties so **Properties Window** not look messy!!!

Comment: Hmm, a little looking turned up [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1005837/How-to-create-user-control-with-nested-properties). Sadly I don't know if this will help. I don't know anything much about custom controls.

Comment: Hm, it looks promising as code example... I'll study it. Thank you for your time my friend!!!